# Calculate the shortest continuous path between shapes without passing thru other shapes in a specific order?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I have the following points, shapes and paths I would like to calculate how to go thru:

[image: Example]

We do not have to move in a diagonal direction if that poses a problem. Here would be the movement with just up, down, left, and right movements between shapes:

[image]

As you can see, I first have a circle. Going to that circle from the bottom left and around it, hitting each point is simple. BUT...the second shape is in the top right corner which is a square so I have to go around the shape in between them (so I dont cross it) and hit each of the points all around that square. Once there, I go to the middle, hit each of the points of the star and done. Once that is done, going backwards is pretty easy.

This is a easy example but of course, there can be 100s of shapes inbetween each of them and I have to go to each in the order they are stated.

The main thing I am looking for is how do I calculate a path AROUND a shape that is between another shape which I have to go to first? Im not sure what algorithm to look for. Is it a Travelling salesman problem? A*?

EDIT: The shapes are defined on a grid. This is what I mean:

[image: Grid representation]

"1" means it must go thru here and "0" is empty space which can be used to get to from one path to another.

Comment: This is not a mathematics question, but a computational geometry question. And for it to be answerable in the first place, you have to specify how exactly your shapes are given as input.

Comment: I was actually going to add that right now. It can be expressed as a grid. give me a moment....

Comment: Well it is an algorithm question, so usually such questions are asked at other SE sites like cs.stackexchange.com. Secondly, you used "continuous" but your clarification shows that it is nothing to do with continuity. Finally, is this schoolwork?

Comment: @user21820: Computational geometry is perfectly on topic here, as are algorithms for solving such problems.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and reposted at cs.stackexchange.com. What I ment by continuous is that it must keep going thru the entire path without jumping to another point and must be able to go backwards once done (backwards is easy). And no, this is not schoolwork.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. On the one hand you say you have to go around the star shape **so that you don't cross it**, but if all you care about is not crossing it then you shouldn't be tracing out the shape. On the other hand you say that you must pass through all the 1's, which is not about crossing.

Comment: I have to find a path around the star shape (without tracing it) because it is the third shape I have to go to. Once I do (trace) the second shape, which is the square, THEN, I can go to the star and trace around the star shape.

Comment: can we move diagonally then, or only like in taxi-cab geometry?

Comment: Ah I see now I understand your problem. About the images, it's because you didn't have enough reputation yet, so Jon helped you to include them. I think you need at least a bit of reputation for a lot of features. One more thing, use `@<username>` somewhere in your comment if you want that user to be notified, otherwise they may not be. (This only works for the first `@`.)

Comment: And I second Jon's question. If we can move diagonally, then we shouldn't be moving to the second shape in the manner shown in your first picture.

Comment: We can move in any way from one shape to another as long as it doesnt cross any other shapes so we can follow the order of each shape. Horizontal, vertical, diagonal and spline movements are allowed.

Comment: well how do you move diagonally in computational geometry?

Comment: If you do not want to move diagonally, then be my guest and do: Down,left,down,left,down,left until you reach the star lol...Im just stating there isnt any limitation of that sort.

Comment: Cleared up the diagonal issue just in case :)